# Saving changes made while iterating across sheets in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to iteratively update the formatting of tabs in an Excel file using openpyxl. The problem is my conditional formatting code (which should work) does not show up in the output excel file.

I think this might be a problem with how I am opening and then closing the active work sheet - I am confused how the active property changes when iterating across sheets.

```
# load Excel file
wb = load_workbook()

# loop through sheets in Excel file
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:

    # set the active sheet
    wb.active = wb[sheet]
    ws = wb[sheet]

    # add conditional formatting to a specific column
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(...)
```

Comment: The conditional formatting code has worked on past projects, and I am almost entirely certain that there is no problem there.

Comment: You'll need to save the file to see any changes.